# Javascript replace not affecting all array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The code below is supposed to replace all of the array values with a span that formats it to a different colour. Unfortunately, this is only working for the fifth array value and not any others. I am unsure where the mistake is. Code and fiddle are below:

```js
var names = ["JakeP97", "Trishy", "Puffs", "Evilgenious", "Joeyc", "TheKid"];
var namecolours = ["red", "pink", "yellow", "white", "green", "blue"];

var tribechat = document.getElementsByClassName('tribeconvo');
for (var i = 0; i < tribechat.length; i++) {
  colourallocate(names[i], namecolours[i]);
}

function colourallocate(chatname, chatcolour) {
  var s = tribechat[i].innerHTML;
  s = s.replace(chatname, '<span style="color:' + chatcolour + '">' + chatname + '</span>');
  tribechat[i].innerHTML = s;
}
```

```html
<div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: hey everyone</div>
<div class="tribeconvo">JakeP97: hello joey</div>
<div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: oi m8, whats up</div>
<div class="tribeconvo">TheKid: LOL hey JakeP</div>
<div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: RIP</div>
```

Comment: You only replace `names[0]` in `tribechat[0]`, `names[1]` in `tribechat[1]`, and so on. The only one where the name matches the DIV is `tribechat[5]`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert in this so I will ask for you to clarify further. You are saying that the only reason why this is working for the 5th one is because `Joeyc` is the 5th value in the array and his name is in the 5th instance of class `tribeconvo`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: No, the reason was that your replace doesn't find anything except for the 5th element. The first message poster's name isn't JakeP97 in your HTML so it can't work and so on. The 5th one was a coincidence, that's why it seemed to work. See my answer for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not performing all the color replacements in every DIV. You just replace `names[0]` in `tribechat[0]`, `names[1]` in `tribechat[1]`. You need to loop through all the names, trying all of the replacements.

```js
var names = ["JakeP97", "Trishy", "Puffs", "Evilgenious", "Joeyc", "TheKid"];
var namecolours = ["red", "pink", "yellow", "white", "green", "blue"];

var tribechat = document.getElementsByClassName('tribeconvo');
for (var i = 0; i < tribechat.length; i++) {
  colourallocate(tribechat[i]);
}

function colourallocate(chat) {
  var s = chat.innerHTML;
  for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
    s = s.replace(names[j], '<span style="color:' + namecolours[j] + '">' + names[j] + '</span>');
    if (s != chat.innerHTML) {
      tribechat[i].innerHTML = s;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: hey everyone</div>
<div class="tribeconvo">JakeP97: hello joey</div>
<div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: oi m8, whats up</div>
<div class="tribeconvo">TheKid: LOL hey JakeP</div>
<div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: RIP</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code wasn't working because the order of your names did not match with that of your html elements. You can't use your names as keys because you arrays aren't unique either. I suggest this sollution in order to pair names with colors based on an index.

```js
var names =       ["Joeyc", "JakeP97", "TheKid"];
var namecolours = ["green", "pink", "blue"];
 
  
 var tribechat = document.getElementsByClassName('tribeconvo');
 for(var i = 0; i < tribechat.length; i++)
 {
  colourallocate(tribechat[i]);
 }
 
 function colourallocate(tribechatParameter) {
    var currentName = tribechatParameter.childNodes[0].innerText; // Finds the span
    var propperIndex = names.indexOf(currentName);
  var s = tribechatParameter.innerHTML;
  s = s.replace(currentName, '<span style="color:' + namecolours[propperIndex] + '">' + currentName + '</span>');
  tribechatParameter.innerHTML = s;
 }
```

```html
<div class="tribeconvo"><span class="name">Joeyc</span>: hey everyone</div>
<div class="tribeconvo"><span class="name">JakeP97</span>: hello joey</div>
<div class="tribeconvo"><span class="name">Joeyc</span>: oi m8, whats up</div>
<div class="tribeconvo"><span class="name">TheKid</span>: LOL hey JakeP</div>
<div class="tribeconvo"><span class="name">Joeyc</span>: RIP</div>
<div class="tribeconvo"><span class="name">TheKid</span>: LOL hey JakeP</div>
```

Comment: In my real application, I would need all of the Joeyc's to be green, regardless of which `tribeconvo` they are sitting in. I just need the position of the name to match the position of the colour, everything else needs to apply to all of the classes.

Comment: I was thinking. Maybe you wanted to have pairs of name and color based on an index in an array, in which case this last edit is it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are referencing the variable `i` inside the function `colourallocate`, however `i` is declared outside of the scope of `colourallocate`:

```
function colourallocate(chatname, chatcolour) {
  var s = tribechat[i].innerHTML; // here `i` is not defined
  s = s.replace(chatname, '<span style="color:' + chatcolour + '">' + chatname + '</span>');
  tribechat[i].innerHTML = s; // again here `i` is not defined
}
```

You probably want to do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tribechat.length; i++) {
  colourallocate(i)
}

function colourallocate(i) {
  var s = tribechat[i].innerHTML;
  var chatname = names[i];
  var chatcolour = namecolours[i];
  s = s.replace(chatname, '<span style="color:' + chatcolour + '">' + chatname + '</span>');
  tribechat[i].innerHTML = s;
}
```

Although given the simplicity of the 2 functions you could probably combine them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tribechat.length; i++) {
  var s = tribechat[i].innerHTML;
  var chatname = names[i];
  var chatcolour = namecolours[i];
  s = s.replace(chatname, '<span style="color:' + chatcolour + '">' + chatname + '</span>');
  tribechat[i].innerHTML = s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a separate function to perform the changes. You may do that inside the loop, like this:

```
var names = ["JakeP97", "Trishy", "Puffs", "Evilgenious", "Joeyc", "TheKid"];
var namecolours = ["red", "pink", "yellow", "white", "green", "blue"];

var tribechat = document.getElementsByClassName('tribeconvo');

for(var i=0; i<tribechat.length; i++) {
  arrs = tribechat[i].innerHTML.split(': ');
  tribechat[i].innerHTML = '';
  span1 = document.createElement('span');
  span1.innerHTML = arrs[0] + ': ';
  span1.setAttribute('style','color:' + namecolours[names.indexOf(arrs[0])]);
  span2 = document.createElement('span');
  span2.innerHTML = arrs[1];
  tribechat[i].appendChild(span1);
  tribechat[i].appendChild(span2);  
}
```

In the line

```
span1.setAttribute('style','color:' + namecolours[names.indexOf(arrs[0])]);
```

where you set the `style` attribute for the first `span` element, you use the name in `arrs[0]` to grab the index of the corresponding color in `namecolours`.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/eddealmeida/k6hr1vja/)